# How can I convert a tensor into a ndarray in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

My goal is to convert a tensor into a ndarray without 'run' or 'eval'.
I wanted to perform the same operation as the example.

```py
A = tf.constant(5)
B = tf.constant([[A, 1], [0,0]])
```

However, ndarray can be inside tf.constant but tensor cannot.
Therefore, I tried to perform the operation using the following example, but tf.make_ndarray does not work.

```py
A = tf.constant(5)
C = tf.make_ndarray(A)
B = tf.constant([[C, 1], [0,0]])
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28840#issuecomment-509551333

As mentioned in the github link above, tf.make_ndarray does not work.
To be precise, an error occurs because tensorflow requires a 'tensor_shape' that does not exist, instead of a 'shape' that exists.

How can I run the code in this situation?

Comment: [`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) expects a [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto) (e.g. read from a serialized graph or made with [`tf.make_tensor_proto`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_tensor_proto)), not a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) is used to convert [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto) values into NumPy arrays. These values are generally the constants used in a graph. For example, when you use [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), you create a `Const` operation with an attribute `value` holding the constant value that the operation will produce. That attribute is stored as a [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto). Hence, you can "extract" the value of a `Const` operation as a NumPy array like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant(5)
C = tf.make_ndarray(A.op.get_attr('value'))
print(C, type(C))
# 5 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

In general, though, you cannot convert arbitrary tensors into NumPy arrays, as their values will depend on the values of the variables and the fed inputs within a particular session.