# tensorflow reload mode to session from graph def

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an exported tensorflow saved model which is used for serving.
I want to "reload" it from graphdef object, which I can broadcast for usage with spark.
I load it using:

```
sess = tf.Session()
tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ['serve'], folder)
sess.run('dense_1/Softmax:0', {'input_1:0': input_image})  # works
```

Then, to load it again to different session, I've tried:

```
graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()

# then, to load
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
   tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
   sess.run('dense_1/Softmax:0', {'input_1:0': input_image})
```

I get the error:
`FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value dense_1/kernel`

I've tried adding 
`sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`
But still the same error.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot copy variable values from one session to another through the graphdef. The variable values are stored within the session, and the graph definition only contains the structure of the graph. You need to "export" the variable values from one session and then restore them in the other. If you want to avoid using checkpoints or similar tooling, you can use a function that should work in most cases like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Gets variable values as a list of pairs with the name and the value
def get_variable_values(sess):
    # Find variable operations
    var_ops = [op for op in sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == 'VariableV2']
    # Get the values
    var_values = []
    for v in var_ops:
        try:
            var_values.append(sess.run(v.outputs[0]))
        except tf.errors.FailedPreconditionError:
            # Uninitialized variables are ignored
            pass
    # Return the pairs list
    return [(op.name, val) for op, val in zip(var_ops, var_values)]

# Restore the variable values
def restore_var_values(sess, var_values):
    # Find the variable initialization operations
    assign_ops = [sess.graph.get_operation_by_name(v + '/Assign') for v, _ in var_values]
    # Run the initialization operations with the given variable values
    sess.run(assign_ops, feed_dict={op.inputs[1]: val
                                    for op, (_, val) in zip(assign_ops, var_values)})

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    v = tf.Variable(0., tf.float32, name='a')
    v.load(3., sess)
    var_values = get_variable_values(sess)
    graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")
    restore_var_values(sess, var_values)
    print(sess.run('a:0'))
    # 3.0
```

Comment: Does the graphdef contains any weights? I do see some nodes have `tensor_content` attribute, but others are indeed empty.

Comment: @user3599803 The graphdef contains some actual values, mostly constants in the graph (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57474659/1782792) shows how to extract a constant from the graph definition, and also things like axes, shapes, ...). However, trainable parameters are variables which do not have their value stored in the graph. For variables initialized with a constant value (as this example), a `Const` operation (with the name `var_name/initial_value`) holding that value is created, but that is only used on initialization.

Comment: I still get the error `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value batch_normalization_91/moving_mean/local_step_4`   when running the line: `var_values = sess.run([v.outputs[0] for v in var_ops])`

Comment: @user3599803 Well you need to have the variables in the first session initialized before being able to extract their values. I changed the code so uninitialized variables are just ignored. However, they will need to be eventually initialized somehow if you want to use them.

Comment: Cool, that works. Last question, I see in keras code, `model.get_weights()` does one call for session.run(). Is it efficient to call sess.run() in a loop? Cause it seems to run somewhat slow.

Comment: @user3599803 Calling `sess.run()` in a loop is not unusual, in fact training loops are typically exactly that. It may depend on what you are running though. If you retrieve the weights on every loop iteration it may slow things down, since you are constantly pulling a significant amount of memory from the GPU to the CPU (assuming you are using CPU). Also, make sure you are not adding new ops to the graph on every loop iteration, as that will have a negative impact on the performance.